# Use grid inside collapse body

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

In the below snippet I have a collapse which shows if you hover over the second nav-link item. Now I want to use the Grid system inside this collapse but I can't seem to make it work.

**What does not work?**
The columns just display underneath one another.

How do I use the grid system inside the collapse body?

```js
$(".menu1").hover(
 function() {
    $('.panel').collapse('show');
  }, function() {
    $('.panel').collapse('hide');
  }
);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link menu1" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="panel collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">Test - Column</div>
          <div class="col-md-6">Test - Column</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you want to create a aimple mega menu with bootstrap [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-with-tabs-navigation) can help you

Comment: @SyedMunisAli That example seems to use bootstrap 3 and I am using bootstrap 4. I am unable to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?
This is in Bootstrap 3
All I did was wrap your `row` in a `container`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/Lfypu5ay/)

Comment: Exactly what i meant. Thx

Comment: sure its because of this? because even without the container it works for me as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/7gyvfk71/ which makes sense if you ask me.. I think the problem was with the Window-Size beeing simply to small for col-md-*

Comment: @Simon It did not work for me on my end. Not without the container surrounding it.

Comment: It can run without the container div but not necessarily with the desired results.